# Codeigniter retrieve top 5 most occurring rows in column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I currently am using codeigniter 3 to build a website. I have been able to build a full gallery and cart system using the database and active record. As well as a backend. I am currently now working the charts.js to build a pie graph in the backend of the 5 top sellers on the site. As well I will be making a graph for items sold by hour using the line graph. I can make the charts appear with dummy data no problem, however I am running into an issue of trying to retrieve the right data from the DB. It appears the query is going to be quite complex.

My mysql table is named `order_items`. And in order items there is a column `qty` and a column `product_type`. Both return integers. What I need is to find which five items have sold the most quantity. Eventually I will need to add the data to my charts.js setup as follows. Anyone with advanced experience with codeigniter active record?

```
var pieData = [{
    value : 300,
    color : "#F7464A",
    highlight : "#FF5A5E",
    label : "Product 1"
}, {
    value : 125,
    color : "#46BFBD",
    highlight : "#5AD3D1",
    label : "Product 2"
}, {
    value : 100,
    color : "#FDB45C",
    highlight : "#FFC870",
    label : "Product 3"
}, {
    value : 40,
    color : "#949FB1",
    highlight : "#A8B3C5",
    label : "Product 4"
}, {
    value : 20,
    color : "#4D5360",
    highlight : "#616774",
    label : "Product 5"
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this script,

```
$data = $this->db->select('*')
                 ->from('order_items,SUM(qty) as total_qty')
                 ->order_by('total_qty','desc')
                 ->limit(5)
                 ->group_by('product_id')
                 ->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: I tried something like this originally but all that gets me is the last 5 records, with the highest quantity. It doesn't actually look for a total of all the quantity for a product id. I think in the meantime I may have found my solution using php

Comment: @user1881482,please take a look i have updated my answer

Comment: I tried that though i get this error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(qty) as total_qty GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY total_qty DESC LIMIT 5 at line 2`

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution using php in case some one else stumbles upon this. If there is a better way to do this using mysql I would be glad to learn something. Here is my php function getting the results I need.

```
$query = $this -> db -> get('order_items');
$array = array();
foreach ($query -> result() as $result) {
    $key = $result -> product_id;
    $value = $result -> qty;
    if (!isset($array[$key])) {
        $array[$key] = $value;
    } else if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
        $old = $array[$key];
        $array[$key] = $value + $old;
    } 
}
arsort($array);
$newArray = array_slice($array, 0, 5, true);
return $newArray;
```

In the last few hours I have done some mysql tutorials and learned a lot about join, order and limit. Below is what I finally used to get what I needed.

```
$select = array('products.name as label', 'sum(order_items.qty) as value');
$final = $this -> db -> select($select)
               -> from('products') 
               -> join('order_items', 'order_items.product_id = products.id', 'left') 
               -> group_by('products.id') 
               -> order_by('value', 'DESC') 
               -> limit(5) 
               -> get() -> result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$data = $this->db->select('id, product_id, SUM(quantity) as total_qty')
                 ->from('table')
                 ->order_by('total_qty','desc')
                 ->limit(5)
                 ->group_by('product_id')
                 ->get()->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getAllBestsaller() {  

    $result = array();
    $returndata = array();
    $this->db->select("*, SUM(total_sale) as total_sale");
    $this->db->from("{$this->tblproducts}");

    $this->db->where('isactive', 1 );
    $this->db->order_by('total_sale','desc');
    $this->db->limit(2);
    $this->db->group_by('product_id');
    $aQuery = $this->db->get();
    $this->db->last_query();
    if($aQuery -> num_rows() >0 ){
        $returndata = $aQuery->result();
    }
    return $returndata;
}
```